# How to categorize reports XAF

Tags: c#, devexpress, xaf

I am using XAF,now I need to categorize reports as  master-detail view. I  created Custom Report Class as in this example:
http://documentation.devexpress.com/#xaf/CustomDocument3243  and a Category class inherited from HCategory. I used Category class instead of AdditionalInfo field.There is no problem here ,but I don't know how to associate them,send selected Category to ListView and show them as master-detail. Can you help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the simplest case, it is sufficient to just add a public HCategory ReportCategory { ... } property into your custom ReportData class, and then group the ListView by this category column.
If you want, you can make a true association between your custom ReportData and HCategory descendants [as described in the documentation here](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#XafFaq/CustomDocument3059).

See also [a similar request in this regard](http://www.devexpress.com/issue=S36554).
If you require more assistance on this task, please contact [the DevExpress Support Team](http://www.devexpress.com/sc) (it is free during the 30 day evaluation period). This way you will get a guaranteed solution in less than 24 hours (except for public weekends).

**UPDATE:**
Here is the discussion created in the DevExpress Support Center on your behalf:
http://www.devexpress.com/issue=Q441993

Comment: Hi Dennis,thanks for your help,I tried to add HCategory,in fact I used this link for help http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/E1881.aspx .I wanted to replace string additionalinfo with ReportCategory category .ReportCategory is derived from HCategory. But I had serialization exception or session exception. I know the reason,ReportCategory must be Serializable , but could not do that, in every attempt, I had different exception.Is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: Rauf, thank you for the update. I will do my best to find a solution for you and post it in the ticket you created in our Support Center. Please bear with me!